# How can I unpack non-iterable items?

Tags: python, probability, probability-theory, probability-distribution

This is my code:

```
d={(i,j):i+j for i in range(1,7) for j in range(1,7)}

from collections import defaultdict 
dinv = defaultdict(list) 
for i,j in d.values(): 
    dinv[j].append(i)

X={i:len(j)/36. for i,j in dinv.iteritems() } 
print (X)
```

This is my traceback error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d6b279f4a6a8> in <module>
      4 from collections import defaultdict
      5 dinv = defaultdict(list)
----> 6 for i,j in d.values():
      7     dinv[j].append(i)
      8 

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: The values are a list of int so you cannot unpack to i and j, What do you want to do ? The key is a 2-element tuple by the way

Answer (score 1):

To iterate on key and values, you need to use `.items()` also you'd better use better names for your variables

```
dinv = defaultdict(list) 
for pair,v_sum in d.items(): 
    dinv[v_sum].append(pair)
```

Next you'll that `defaultdict` has no attribute `iteritems`, use `items` too

```
X = {key:len(values)/36. for key,values in dinv.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `d.items()` or `d.keys()` (or just `d`) instead of `d.values()` in `for i,j in d.values():`.